# smartface.io WebView does not let me load a local html file

Tags: smartface.io

I'm tearing my hair out.  The Smartface Webview does not work with local files.  Doing this for Smartface, IOS iphone 6.

I followed the instructions online for creating a webview by calling a simple hello world html file.  However, when calling an actual url (like www.google.com), it works just fine.  Help!

Code Snippet:

webviewMain = new SMF.UI.WebView({
top: "0%",
left: "0%",
width:"100%",
height:"87%",
URL: "hello.html"
});

Answer (score 0):

There was a known issue about user created html's in webview. It is already fixed for the new version of Smartface(4.5.0). It will be released in two or three days at most.

Comment: Hi. I installed 4.5 but the problem still persists. Are you sure the problem is fixed?